# Imprimir diversos registros em uma tabela a partir de uma entrada de dados

Tags: javascript, html, mysql, express.js

Estou tentando imprimir em uma tabela todos os registros a partir de uma busca utilizando o método fetch. A pessoa utiliza uma entrada de dados para selecionar o nome e com isso todos que tiverem o mesmo nome é impresso na tabela. Da maneira que fiz o looping ele só está imprimindo o ultimo registro. Se alguem puder me ajudar, ficarei grato.

-HTML code-

```
`<div id="resultados" class="resultado">
                        <table class="tabela-container">
                            <tr class="tabela-header">
                                <th>Nome</th>
                                <th>Departamento</th>
                                <th>Função</th>
                            </tr>
                            <tr class="teste">
                                <td class="teste-nome"></td>
                                <td class="teste-depart"></td>
                                <td class="teste-funcao"></td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </div>`
```

`-JS Code-`

```
function pesquisaRegistro() {
    
    var myHeaders = new Headers();
    myHeaders.append("Content-Type", "application/json");
    var options = {
        method: "GET",
        headers: myHeaders,
        cache: "default"
    }

    const btnRegistro = document.querySelector('#pesquisa');

    btnRegistro.onclick = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        const entradaRegistro = document.querySelector('#escolhe-nome').value;
        
        const showData = (result) => {
            for(var i in result){
                    const listaNome = document.querySelector(".teste-nome");
                    const listaDepart = document.querySelector(".teste-depart");
                    const listaFuncao = document.querySelector(".teste-funcao");

                    listaNome.innerHTML = result[i].nome;
                    listaDepart.innerHTML = result[i].departamento;
                    listaFuncao.innerHTML = result[i].funcao;

                    console.log(i);
                }
            }

        fetch(`${entradaRegistro}`, options)
        .then(response => {
            response.json()
        .then(data => showData(data))
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: Oque o seu result tá devolvendo ?

Comment: Da forma que está no código ele me retorna cada objeto que ele percorrer, porém na tela ele só imprime o último. 

Dessa forma se eu pesquisar meu nome por ex, ele retorna um objeto pra cada um que tiver cadastrado com o mesmo nome.

Answer (score 0):

O problema do seu algoritimo esta na utilização do **[HTMLElementObject.innerHTML](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_html_innerhtml.asp)**.
Você esta subistituindo o seu HTML e não concatenando, então ao invés de de **HTMLElementObject.innerHTML = "text"** você deve usar **HTMLElementObject.innerHTML += "text"**.

Comment: Realmente, fiz a alteração no código e já surtiu efeito, muito obrigado pela ajuda.

Comment: Favor sinalizar resposta como resposta útil